# Alternative document structure in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

In a JTextPane with a DefaultStyledDocument the document structure (hierarchy of Element objects) ends with a LeafElement that spans all the character of the enclosing paragraph. Is there a way to customize the document such that each leaf element will represent a single character?

(Background: I am trying to implementing a custom coloring scheme - somewhat similar to  syntax coloring in an IDE. Using setCharacterAttributes() for this purpose is not an option, mainly due to performance considerations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in [jsyntaxpane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/).  It uses a PlainDocument instead of using the more resource hungry StyledDocument.  A Leaf for each character will require lots of memory, so you may want to use a leaf for each "Token".

You can also use a StyledDocument then update the style for each Token in a separate Thread.